# how to prevent an app from crushing while it was calculating the Average of n number while the user enter a String and not an Integer

Tags: java

here is my code

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication2;

import java.util.Scanner;


/**write a java program that take  three Numbers as input and print the average of the numbers 
 * 
 *
 * @author takenoLAB
 */
public class Average {
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner  input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.err.println("enter your numbers separated by ,");
    String n = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("here is your average "+cal(n));
    }
    public static double cal(String data){
    String [] datas=data.split(",");
    double tota=0;
     double avr=0;
     try{
     for (int i=0;i<datas.length;i++){
         tota+=Integer.parseInt(datas[i]);
     }
      avr = tota/datas.length;
     }
    
     catch(Exception err){}
     return avr;
    }
    
   
    
}
```

Comment: [It doesn't crash](https://ideone.com/pOrSon) it just prints `0.0`, so what is the problem you're facing? Do you want to ignore invalid inputs entirely, by exiting the program, or simply skipping over them in the average calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Use this, only when you encounter an integer add it to total and increase the counter. Result will be depend on how many actual integers were present

```
public static double cal(String data) {
        String[] datas = data.split(",");
        double tota = 0;
        double avr = 0;
        int count = 0;

        for (String s: datas)
        {
            try{
                tota += Integer.parseInt(s);
                count++;
            } catch(NumberFormatException ne)
            {
                
            }
        }
        
        avr = tota / count;
        return avr;
    }
```

Output:

```
enter your numbers separated by ,
5,2,3,a,5
4
here is your average 3.75
```

Comment: Well can you accept as an answer and close this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [StringUtils.isNumeric()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) method. For example:

```
if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(s) && StringUtils.isNumeric(s)){
     tota += Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

So, it will add only the valid inputs from the user and ignore all the other invalid data (blank, empty spaces, strings which are not numbers) and none exception will occur.

Comment: Also we should not use datas.length as divisor, as it can have non int values too

Comment: @SabareeshMuralidharan it is irrelevant with my answer what you are writing. I answer what the OP asked. Secondly, what you are writing is wrong, the `avr` will always be a `double`. What the OP should check is if the `datas.length` is 0, which currently will lead to an exception.

Comment: take your time, read my comment again w.r.t to OP's code